# install two wireshark through command in line silent mode on window

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, wireshark

I am looking for the way where i can install two Wireshark version using window command line.

I am trying below PowerShell command, it is working fine but deleting old one. Is there any way to keep both version and install automatically from PowerShell without user intervention.

```
Start-Process Wireshark-win64-2.6.6.exe -Wait -ArgumentList @('/NCRC', '/S', '/desktopicon=no' ,'/quicklaunchicon=no', '/D=C:\Program Files\Wireshark2');
```

Thanks
Shrwan

Comment: This is not a programming issue. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is a more appropriate place for asking this kind of question.

Comment: Ditto to what Ansgar said, and by extension, this is the installer removing adding / removing its bits, not PowerShell. You are just using PowerShell to run the installer.